# Hibernate, MySQL, Enum, and NULL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, enums, null

I am using MySQL database with Hibernate and there are certain Enum fields that allow NULL or empty values. It is all fine until a query is made and Hibernate tries to map the empty value on the Enum defined. I am unable to define a value in Enum that would work, because Enum does allow white-spaces.

Enum class:

```
private enum ObjType {
    itemA,
    itemB,
    NULL
}
```

It takes NULL as a member but that does not help. I am new to EE Java, and would appreciate any help.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can add a `unknown` or `default` or `invalid` value to your enum which will be mapped in case if it is `null` or `empty space`

```
package com.test;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class Brand{
    private static HashMap<String,BrandName> map = new HashMap<String,BrandName>();
public enum BrandName {
    HERO("hero"),HONDA("honda"),UNKNOWN("default");

    private String value = null;

     private BrandName(String value){
         this.value = value;
         addToMap();
     }

     private void addToMap(){
         map.put(this.value, this);
     }

     @Override
     public String toString(){
         return this.value;
     }

     public static BrandName fromValue(String value){
         return map.get(value) != null ? map.get(value) : map.get("default");
     }
}
}
```

Using `fromValue` method you can get enum object from value. 
using `toString` method you can get value of an enum object.
`map` will contain value to enum object mapping. If the value like `null` or `empty space` does not exist in map, the map will return null and in that case the method `fromValue` will return `UNKNOWN` enum object.

```
System.out.println(Brand.BrandName.HERO.toString());
        System.out.println(Brand.BrandName.fromValue("").toString());
        System.out.println(Brand.BrandName.fromValue(null).toString());
        System.out.println(Brand.BrandName.fromValue("honda").toString());
```

Comment: added the code.. this is the proper and flexible way to use an emun.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a default value to set the column to the NULL enum field in your entity.

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name="obj_type", columnDefinition="char(20) default 'NULL'")
ObjType objType;
```

and update existing rows.

```
update table set obj_type='NULL' where obj_type IS NULL
```

btw I would call the enum fields UNKNOWN because it could be confused with DB NULL-value.

Comment: It will work, but I am looking for a non-intrusive solution, for cases when I do not want to modify the original data.